# How to locate a pointed div element in css

Tags: html, css

I need help in designing my div element as my tooltip. Below are my css scripts which has a design where the pointed arrow is on the left side of the div. How do I transfer the pointed arrow of the div on the right side? Thanks...

```
<div id="tooltip" style="display:none" class="balloon">  
<div class="arrow"></div>
   Content of my tooltip

</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.balloon
    {  
    background: #ccc;  
    height:80px;
    border-radius: 4px;  
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;  
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;  
    position:absolute;
    padding: 20px;  

    font-size: 12px;  
    width: 300px;  
    text-align: justify;  
    color: #3a3a3a; 

    z-index: 200; right: 0; top: 360px; left: 600px
    }  

  .balloon .arrow 
    {  
    border-color: transparent #CCCCCC transparent transparent;  
    border-style: solid;  
    border-width: 10px;  
    display: block;  
    height: 0;  
    left: -20px; 
    position: absolute; 
    top: 20px;  
    width: 0;  
   }
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**Try This: - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/gzmbeurz/)**

```css
.balloon {
    background: #ccc;
    height:80px;
    border-radius: 4px;
    -moz-border-radius: 4px;
    -webkit-border-radius: 4px;
    position:absolute;
    padding: 20px;
    font-size: 12px;
    width: 300px;
    text-align: justify;
    color: #3a3a3a;
    z-index: 200;
    right: 0;
    top: 50px;
    left: 50px
}
.balloon .arrow {
    border-color: transparent transparent transparent #CCCCCC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    right: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    width: 0;
}
```

```html
<div id="tooltip" class="balloon">
    <div class="arrow"></div>
    Content of my tooltip
</div>
```

---

As [@misterManSam](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26417131/how-to-locate-a-pointed-div-element-in-css/26417233#comment41481545_26417233) suggested in his comment you could also make it a pseudo arrow element instead.

**JSFiddle - [DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/oqx9p6bd/)**

Comment: Make it a pseudo arrow element instead, for MOAR awesome? `.balloon:after { content: '';
border-color: transparent transparent transparent #CCCCCC;
    border-style: solid;
    border-width: 10px;
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    right: -20px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 20px;
    width: 0; }`

Comment: @Mary  When you make it pseudo arrow?How does it differs from the first one we made? Any relevance?

Comment: @timmack in that demo I didn't use an extra div to make an arrow, instead I used `:after` pseudo element for it.

Answer (score 1):

In your `.balloon .arrow` css rule, change `left:-20px;` to `right:-20px;`.  Then it will look like @MaryMelody's Demo JSFiddle.